Restart SQL in another Oracle session in-flight?
Has anyone ever figured out some trick to get an in-flight SQL execution in another session to restart? Adaptive features clearly have the capability of restarting after a bit with a different plan; is there a secret way to "nudge" this to force it to happen? I'm pretty sure the conventional answer is No, but perhaps someone has some esoteric approach that actually works?
Use case: if we have an abusive job and we mitigate by lowering consumer group or disabling cell offloading (for Exadata) or lowering DOP of the table involved, is there a way to get the current SQL to start over without throwing an exception to the user so it can pick up some of these changes? Obviously we can kill it and wait for them to restart, but if that raises hackles, is there a more subtler way to do this?
I've tried various combinations of dbms_system.set_bool_param_in_session to disable offload processing, dbms_resource_manager.switch_consumer_group_for_sess, invalidating the cursor by a DDL on the table, and oradebug suspend/resume. Nothing seems to restart a currently running SQL or impact its I/O mechanism in any way. They would only have effect on the next execution.
